# express-ejs-layouts ignore some files (don't add layout to some files)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I want to use `ejs layouts` to only some of the files (not the whole project). But using `express-ejs-layouts` it uses layout to all files. Here is the core part of the code.

```
app.get("/page1",(req,res)=>{
  res.render("p1");
});

app.get("/page2",(req,res)=>{
  res.render("p2");
});

app.get("/page3",(req,res)=>{
  // Don't add Layout file in this page
  res.render("p3",{
    layout:null
  });
});
```

I found in stackoverflow that you can use multiple layouts by passing an `object` having a `key` `layout` and its `value` as name of layout file `{ layout : "layoutNumberOne" }`. But setting its value to `undefined` or `null` doesn't work. And the solution I want is not to create an empty layout file and passing the name of that file in the `object` to the `render()` function which will work, because if that is the case I will have to specify the `{ layout : "emptyLayout" }` in all the pages which I have a lot. I am looking for an answer that can add a `layout` to a specific `route`, so that all requests in the route will have this layout file and will not affect other paths. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you could write a helper function like this:

```
function demo(route, view, data={}){
    app.get(route, (req, res) => {
        let options;
        if(route === "/page3"){
            options = {
                layout: "blank-layout"
            };
        };
        const locals = {
            ...data,
            ...options
        };
        res.render(view, locals)
    });
}
```

and call it whenever you want to render a page:

```
demo("/page3", "p3", {anything: "whatever you want"})
```

This function takes in a route, view file, and an optional data object in the likely event that you want to pass in some dynamic data to use inside your template.

It sets your desired route, then initialises a variable called "options" to later be passed into the "locals" object below once the if statement has given it a value.

The function then compares the value of your "route" parameter to the route you want to assign some unique options to (in this case "/page3"), should the result be true it'll set the "options" variable to be an object with a property called layout and a value of "blank-layout". The value pertains to the name of the layout file you would like to use so feel free to change that value to suit your needs.

Finally this "options" object is merged with the "data" object you may have passed in earlier (if you didn't pass one in it'll just use an empty object); the result of merging the two objects is stored in the "locals" variable and now contains every property your data object and options object have. This variable is then passed into the render function along with the view file.

*note that you can use multiple if statements to set options for other routes*

Comment: The problem is, page3 is not the only page I want to exclude, there is a lot of pages, can't hardcode it, I was looking for something like: if you don't specify a layout , don't use one, If specified, use that layout. Anyway thanks for the answer.